# C: printf and scanf statement skipped in this case

Tags: c

i want to make 2 lines calculator program but after first printf,scanf it skipped the second statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int a,b,c,d,abcd;
    int e,f,g,h,efgh;
    
    printf("1. "); 
    scanf("(%d+%d)x(%d-%d)",&a,&b,&c,&d);
    printf("2. "); 
    scanf("(%d+%d)x(%d-%d)",&e,&f,&g,&h);
    
    abcd=(a+b)*(c-d);
    efgh=(e+f)*(g-h);
    
    printf("%d %d %d",abcd,efgh);
    return 0;
}
```

and i want to make the program like this:

```
input
 1. (1+2)x(3-4)
 2. (5+6)x(7-8)
```

```
output
-3 -11
```

Comment: Your compiler should at least warn you about that last `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest you read a line of input using `fgets`, then use `sscanf` to parse out the info you need. You will also want to check the return value of `sscanf` to ensure all four values were read. In this case I have made successful input required to break out of an infinite loop (`for (;;) { ... }`).

Please note also that all variables do not need to de declared at the start of a function. Instead they can be declared and initialized at their point of use. In this scenario, I have declared `abcd` and `efgh` later in `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LINE_LEN 256

int main ()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    int e, f, g, h;

    char line[LINE_LEN] = {0};

    for (;;) {
        printf("1. ");
        fgets(line, LINE_LEN, stdin);
        if (sscanf(line, "(%d+%d)x(%d-%d)", &a, &b, &c, &d) == 4)
            break;
 
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad input. Try again.");
    }  

    for (;;) {
        printf("1. ");
        fgets(line, LINE_LEN, stdin);
        if (sscanf(line, "(%d+%d)x(%d-%d)", &e, &f, &g, &h) == 4)
            break;
 
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad input. Try again.");
    } 

    int abcd = (a + b) * (c - d);
    int efgh = (e + f) * (g - h);

    printf("%d\n", abcd);
    printf("%d\n", efgh);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like your answer, I tried to cover more scenarios in mine but yours is way clearer.

Comment: As a newcomer to Stack Overflow, please say "thank you" by marking the answer you feel best answers your question as "accepted."

Answer (score 0):

By some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-do-i-read-a-string-entered-by-the-user-in-c) I copied the function to read from the stdin in C and adapted your example. This is a safe way to handle stdin from a C application.

Also I tried your code and I believe that what was wrong is that some newline gets "trapped" in the stdin, hence the second `scanf` returns before you can write anything. That's why this solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2
static int getLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz) {
    int ch, extra;

    // Get line with buffer overrun protection.
    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", prmpt);
        fflush (stdout);
    }
    if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return NO_INPUT;

    // If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
    // to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.
    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    // Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.
    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}

int main ()
{
    int a,b,c,d,abcd;
    int e,f,g,h,efgh;
    
    int rc;
    char buff[20];
    
    rc = getLine ("1. ", buff, sizeof(buff));
    if (rc == NO_INPUT) {
        // Extra NL since my system doesn't output that on EOF.
        printf ("\nNo input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (rc == TOO_LONG) {
        printf ("Input too long [%s]\n", buff);
        return 1;
    }
    
    sscanf(buff, "(%d+%d)x(%d-%d)",&a,&b,&c,&d);
    
    rc = getLine ("2. ", buff, sizeof(buff));
    if (rc == NO_INPUT) {
        // Extra NL since my system doesn't output that on EOF.
        printf ("\nNo input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (rc == TOO_LONG) {
        printf ("Input too long [%s]\n", buff);
        return 1;
    }
    
    sscanf(buff, "(%d+%d)x(%d-%d)",&e,&f,&g,&h);
    
    printf("Check \n");
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n" ,a,b,c,d);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n" ,e,f,g,h);
    
    abcd=(a+b)*(c-d);
    efgh=(e+f)*(g-h);
    
    printf("Results: %d %d \n",abcd,efgh);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

scanf is wrong..
scanf("%typeOfFirstVariable %typeOfSecondVariable...", &firstVariable, &secondVariable...);

```
int a,b,c,d,abcd;
    int e,f,g,h,efgh;
    
    printf("1. "); 
    scanf("%d %d %d %d)",&a,&b,&c,&d);
    
    ...
    return 0;
```

Comment: Or if you want to take it like this: '1. (1+2)x(3-4)' then as an input use string, and then grab first element as s[1], second as s[3]...

Comment: so, how to read specificly the input?
example: (1+2)x(3-4)
how to read 1 as &a, 2 as &b, 3 as &c, 4 as &c

Comment: This answer reads as a comment rather than an answer without some elaboration.